# Characteristic polynomial possibilities of degree $5$, given $x^2(x+2)$ as minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $x^{2}(x+2)$ is the minimal polynomial of a matrix A of
order $5\times 5$. Specify all possible characteristic polynomials
for this matrix? In each case discuss whether the matrix is
diagonalizable or not.

The first part of the question can be solved easily since the
minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial have the same
roots and the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic
polynomial then we have the characteristic polynomial is one of the
form

$P(x)= x^{4}(x+2)$

$P(x)= x^{3}(x+2)^{2}$

$P(x)=
x^{2}(x+2)^{3}$

What about the second part?

Answer (score 2):

A matrix is only diagonalizable when the minimal polynomial factors completely over distinct linear factors. Since the minimal polynomial of $A$ contains $x^2$ it will not be diagonalizable regardless of its characteristic polynomial. So in the Jordan Canonical form of this matrix you will always have a simple Jordan block: \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation}